# Using UTM Zone for Finland in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, finland

I am new to QGIS.

I am trying to import a shapefile (project boundary) into QGIS but when it asks for the CRS I can't find the zone (35) for Finland (in NAD 83).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might be looking for ETRS89 / TMFIN35 which is used for country-wide mapping. The easting,northing axes order is EPSG:3067 while the northing,easting axes order is EPSG:5048

Comment: Thanks turned out I was looking for EPSG:32635, WGS 84 / UTM zone 35N

Answer (score 7):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Datum:

> **North American Datum 1983 and WGS 84**
>
> The initial definition of NAD 83(1986) was intended to match GRS 80
>   and WGS 84, so many older publications indicate no difference.
>   Subsequent measurements found a difference on the order of a meter
>   over much of the United States. Each datum has undergone refinements
>   with more accurate and later measurements.
>
> NAD 83 is defined to remain constant over time for points on the North
>   American Plate, whereas WGS 84 is defined with respect to the average
>   of stations all over the world. Thus the two systems naturally diverge
>   over time. For much of the United States the relative rate is on the
>   order of 1 to 2 cm per year. Hawaii and the coastal portions of
>   central and southern California west of the San Andreas Fault are not
>   on the North American plate, so their divergence rate differs.

Since you are working on Finnish data, I think you should go for the WGS 84. Then, go for `EPSG:32635, WGS 84 / UTM zone 35N`

Comment: @BighouseProductions rather than saying thanks, accept the answer - https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers